# How to use .show() for JFXSnackbar in java fx

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

How to use `.show()` method on `JFXSnackbar` objects in javafx? when I use `.show()` method in my code the compiler shows me the message `".show() method is private in this library"`. I used `jfoenix-8.0.8` version of jfoenix. Can anyone help out on this?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newest version of JFoenix (jfoenix-8.0.8), the show() method is purposefully encapsulated or hidden in the JFXSnackbar class. In other words, JFXSnackbar handles show() internally. See the `public void enqueue(SnackBarEvent snackbarEvent)` method. [See screenshot of it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr8n5.png).

To use a JFXSnackbar in a program you need to create a new JFXSnackbar object like so:

```
JFXSnackbar snackbar = new JFXSnackbar(rootPane);
```

***The rootPane is the pane that the snackbar will display on.***

Next, you need to create a JFXSnackbar.SnackbarEvent which will describe the behavior of the snackbar, like this:

```
final JFXSnackbar.SnackbarEvent snackbarEvent = new JFXSnackbar.SnackbarEvent(new Label("Some string to display"), Duration.seconds(3.33), null);
```

***I used a null value for the Psuedoclass parameter.*** Still works fine.

Finally, add the JFXSnackbar.SnackbarEvent to the JFXSnackbar object using enque method:

```
snackbar.enqueue(snackbarEvent);
```